# JUnit Label in methods

Tags: junit, label

My method:

`boolean canBuyStorage(Ship shipPlayer, Label lblUpperText);`

I do not know how to substitute Label during testing:

`assertTrue(canBuyStorage(new Ship(), new Label("Test Label)??));`

i got error: 
`"java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError"`

I used JavaFX `@FXML private Label label;` to inform user about results there.

Is there any way to substitute this `Label` during testing or should I use null instead of?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need separate your app into layers. (Model/View/Controller).
For example https://github.com/kasperisager/swing-mvc

For the testing view, you need a create context for Framework (Swing, JavaFX or etc).

For testing business logic your code mustn't know about UI framework.